# Get list of podcast subscriptions and downloaded AppStore applications from iTunes

Tags: com, synchronization, itunes, podcast

So, I'm trying to implement a solution to a problem that [I posted on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/72041/synchronize-podcasts-across-multiple-computers-with-itunes-on-windows).

#### What I'm trying to do

I want to write a (Windows) application to synchronize podcast subscriptions in iTunes (and possibly iPhone/iPod touch apps, though I'll ignore them for now) between multiple computers that are using the same iTunes account.

#### How I'm planning on doing it

My initial thought was to do the following:

1) Grab the list of all podcast subscriptions from iTunes on computer A
 2) Do some synching, giving new podcast urls to a program on computer B
 3) Subscribe to the new podcasts in iTunes with computer B

I think I could do all this by parsing the ITL file, which is where subscription information seem to be stored.  I haven't been able to find any documentation for this, though.

Maybe I'm going about this wrong and using the iTunes COM interface would be a decent way to grab the list of subscribed podcasts (step 1) and then subscribing to them (step 3). Is there a smarter way to go about doing this?

#### Summary

1. Before I reinvent the wheel, is there already a solution for synching podcast subscriptions among multiple computers?
2. What is the most appropriate method for grabbing a list of podcasts that iTunes is subscribed to?
3. What is the most appropriate method of subscribing iTunes to new podcasts?

As a note, I e-mailed Apple's Developer Support with pretty much the same questions, but apparently asking questions about documentation/API doesn't count as technical support.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

On OS X there is no way to get iTunes' list of podcasts. You can ask for podcast tracks (and kind of arrange them by album name), but iTunes will not tell you anything about the actual podcasts themselves (URLs, status, name etc.).

I have zero experience of iTunes on Windows, but I'd be very surprised if the API were more comprehensive than the OS X one.